# How to integrate FirstData as payment gateway?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I want to integrate `FirstData` as my payment gateway.

How to start with this?

I am using php.

Thanks

Code which i have used

```
<? include("ipg-util.php"); ?>
<form method="post" action="https://test.ipg-online.com/connect/gateway/processing">
<input type="hidden" name="txntype" value="sale">
<input type="hidden" name="timezone" value="GMT"/>
<input type="hidden" name="txndatetime" value="<?php echo getDateTime() ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo createHash(13.00,978) ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="storename" value="1909354791"/>
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="payonly"/>
<input type="text" name="chargetotal" value="13.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="978"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite old post, but might be useful for others.

The documentation of First Data Payment Gateway is available [here](https://www.firstdata.com/en_us/customer-center/merchants/support/first-data-global-gateway-api-software-landing.html).

Once your form is set up with your store name and other required information, don't forget  to set up the connection settings in your Global Gateway Virtual Terminal account:

**Production link:** https://www.linkpointcentral.com

**Test link:** https://www.staging.linkpointcentral.com

To do so, go to Administration > Connect Settings, then insert in *Submission Form URL* the URL of the page from which you call the payment service, and the response URLs...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Guillaume.M you are right.
Actually had a problem while integrating the connect, then i contacted support then they told me that the Submission Form URLs are required to do the payment successfully!..

Submission URL are basically the success or thank you page and failure page url.

In the manual avaiable on the telecash documentcenter, they did not added the URL settings step in mandatory..

Then i emailed them, they accepted the suggtion..

Thank you